# Scroll bar with GridLayout(1,1)

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, jtextarea

Here I'm writing a Java program with Swing but I have some trouble. I can add a scroll bar to my text area:

```
    //Text area
    public static JTextArea output = new JTextArea("======================== The Outputs HERE ================================");

   // JBouton 
   private JButton bouton = new JButton();
   private JButton tpBouton = new JButton("TP 205");

   // JLabel
   private JLabel label = new JLabel("TP DE 205");
   public static JLabel initialState = new JLabel("TEST");
   public static JLabel state = new JLabel("");
   public static JLabel tableShow = new JLabel("Entrer l'element a rechercher : ");
   public static JLabel finalState = new JLabel("");
   private JLabel explicitText = new JLabel();

   // JTextField
   private JFormattedTextField input = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
    //JTextField input = new JTextField("Choisir l'element a rechercher ...");

   // JPanel
   JPanel mainBGRadio = new JPanel();
   JPanel secondBGRadio = new JPanel();
   JPanel b7 = new JPanel();
   JPanel main = new JPanel();
   JPanel container = new JPanel();
   JPanel outPutField = new JPanel();

   // Ensemble
   private Ensemble set = new Ensemble();

   // JRadioButton

   // for the main group
   private JRadioButton lookup = new JRadioButton("Look Up");
   private JRadioButton insert = new JRadioButton("Insert");
   private JRadioButton delete = new JRadioButton("Delete");
   private JRadioButton difference = new JRadioButton("Difference");
   private JRadioButton intersection = new JRadioButton("Intersection");
   private JRadioButton union = new JRadioButton("Union");

   // for the second group

   private JRadioButton sortedList = new JRadioButton("liste Trie");
   private JRadioButton simpleList = new JRadioButton("liste Simple");
   private JRadioButton doubleList = new JRadioButton("liste Avec Doublons");
   private JRadioButton simpleVector = new JRadioButton("vecteur Simple");
   private JRadioButton sortedVector = new JRadioButton("vecteur Trie");
   private JRadioButton booleanVector = new JRadioButton("vecteur Boolean");

    // JButtonGroup

    // some bouton group

   private ButtonGroup mainBG = new ButtonGroup();
   private ButtonGroup secondBG = new ButtonGroup();

   // ArrayList

   private ArrayList<JRadioButton> radioList = new ArrayList(){{
        add(lookup);
        add(insert);
        add(delete);
        add(union);
        add(intersection);
        add(difference);
    }};

    private ArrayList<JRadioButton> radioFunctionList = new ArrayList(){{
        add(sortedList);
        add(doubleList);
        add(simpleList);
        add(simpleVector);
        add(sortedVector);
        add(booleanVector);
    }};

    // Font

   Font font = new Font("ubuntu", Font.BOLD, 45);
   Font explicitFont = new Font("ubuntu", Font.BOLD, 15);
   Font stateFont = new Font("ubuntu", Font.BOLD, 25);
   Font textareaFont = new Font("ubuntu", Font.ITALIC, 19);


   public Fenetre(){

   }

/**
 * this is the main window with all its contains element
 */
public void montrer(){

        // window Params
        this.setTitle("TP 205");
        this.setSize(800, 800);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // bouton configuration

        bouton.setText("Simuler");
        bouton.addActionListener(new BtnClass());
        tpBouton.addActionListener(new BtnClass());
        tpBouton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        tpBouton.setFont(explicitFont);
        tpBouton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);


        // JLabel configuration

        explicitText.setText("Bienvenur sur notre tp de 205");
        label.setFont(font);
        explicitText.setFont(explicitFont);
        explicitText.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        state.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        state.setFont(stateFont);
        initialState.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        initialState.setFont(stateFont);
        finalState.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        finalState.setFont(stateFont);

        // input configuration

        input.setFont(explicitFont);
        input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 30));
        input.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        input.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, input.getMinimumSize().height));
        output.setFont(textareaFont);
        output.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        output.setLineWrap(true);

        JScrollPane scrool = new JScrollPane();
        scrool.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("LIONEL"));
        scrool.setViewportView(output);

        // layout configuration

        JPanel b1 = new JPanel();
        b1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        b1.add(label);

        JPanel b2 = new JPanel();
        b2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b2, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        b2.add(explicitText);

        JPanel b3 = new JPanel();
        b3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b3, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        b3.add(tpBouton);
        b3.add(bouton);

        JPanel b4 = new JPanel();
        b4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b4, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        b4.add(state);

        JPanel b5 = new JPanel();
        b5.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b5, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        b5.add(finalState);

        JPanel b6 = new JPanel();
        b6.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b6, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        b6.add(initialState);

        b7.setLayout(new BoxLayout(b7, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        b7.add(tableShow);
        b7.add(input);
        b7.setVisible(false);

        this.setEventSimpleRadio();
        this.setEventSecondRadio();
        secondBGRadio.setVisible(false);
        mainBGRadio.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainBGRadio, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        secondBGRadio.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondBGRadio, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        b1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        b2.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        b3.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        b4.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        b5.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        b6.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        b7.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);


        mainBGRadio.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        secondBGRadio.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        container.add(b1);
        container.add(b2);
        container.add(mainBGRadio);
        container.add(secondBGRadio);
        container.add(b7);
        container.add(b6); 
        container.add(b4); 
        container.add(b5);

        container.add(b3);
        outPutField.add(output);
        outPutField.add(scrool);
        outPutField.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1, 5, 5));
        container.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        main.add(container);
        main.add(outPutField);


        this.setContentPane(main);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
```

Here is a screen shot of what it produces:

[image: code image]

I'm looking for how to solve this problem and show the scroll bar properly just when the text area is overflow and to have a little scroll bar.

Comment: Please post a valid [mcve]. Your code has too much unneeded code, including a whole bunch of unrelated components, as well as not enough code -- there's not enough for us to compile or run it. Also don't add your JTextfield to more than one container. You add it to both the viewport (good) and the JPanel (bad). This last bit removes it from the viewport, and is likely why you're not seeing it.

Comment: In other words, get rid of this line: `outPutField.add(output);` as it's messing you over.

Comment: thakns ... the problem is that ... the program have 4 class files ans every class file have more than 200 lines ... the reasons why i had not import it here ...

Comment: And again, we don't  want to see the entire program. You should create a new small [mcve] program. Please read the link *before* replying.

Answer (score 1):

The basic logic for using a JTextArea would be:

```
//public static JTextArea output = new JTextArea("==== The Outputs HERE =====;
public static JTextArea output = new JTextArea(5, 30);
```

This will allow you to create a text area with 5 rows of data and about 30 characters per line. Once you have more than 5 lines of data the scrollbar will appear.

Then in your constructor you can assign the default text:

```
output = "========= The Outputs HERE ================================");
```

Also, you should NOT be using the static keyword on all your variables. This shows incorrect design of your class. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Area](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for a working example that will show you how to better design your class.

Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Comment: thakns . i have done it like that because many others child class use those varaible in others class for the static devellopement

Comment: @LionelT, `thakns .` - glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: `i have done it like that because...` - again that is a TERRIBLE design. That is not how  the static keyword should be used. The tutorial shows you a better design. Learn a better design approach to make your code easier to maintain and debug.